# How I Do DataGridView Print Text Alignment Center and Font Size Change VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have use the below code it work fine but how i large the font size and how i center text alignment please help me this code worked just center and font size problem this code work but the problem is how i alignment between two row

```
    With DataGridView1
        Using fmt As New StringFormat With {
            .Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
            .LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center,
            .Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter,
            .FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.LineLimit Or StringFormatFlags.NoWrap
        }

            Dim y As Single = e.MarginBounds.Top

            Using headerFont As New Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Bold)

                Do While mRow < .RowCount
                    Dim row As DataGridViewRow = .Rows(mRow)
                    Dim x As Single = e.MarginBounds.Left
                    Dim h As Single = 0

                    For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                        Dim rc As RectangleF = New RectangleF(x, y, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height)



                        If newpage Then
                            e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderText, headerFont, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)  '
                        Else
                            e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Rows(cell.RowIndex).Cells(cell.ColumnIndex).FormattedValue.ToString(), headerFont, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                        End If

                        x += rc.Width
                        h = Math.Max(h, rc.Height)
                    Next
                    newpage = False
                    y += h
                    mRow += 1
                    If y + h > e.MarginBounds.Bottom Then
                        e.HasMorePages = True
                        mRow -= 1
                        newpage = True
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                Loop
            End Using
        End Using
        mRow = 0
    End With
```

Comment: `fmt.Alignment =StringAlignment.Center` to horizontally center the string. To change the font size, create a new font: `Dim newFont = New Font(Font.FontFamily, 12, FontStyle.Bold)` AND don't forget to dispose the disposable objects like `fmt` and `newFont`. Use the `Using ... End Using` block to create the disposable objects.

Comment: not change the font and no change the alignment

Comment: Edit your question to show how are you doing that.

Comment: check the code now

Comment: ok i will post again

Comment: you have to add in number distance between two row s

Comment: i have in the last of all row remove button i want not show the remove button text in print